# what is wrong here : TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, tweepy

```
if e.message[0]['code'] == 32: ##Account suspended : [{u'message': u'Could not authenticate you', u'code': 32}]': ##Account suspended : [{u'message': u'Could not authenticate you', u'code': 32}]
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

I think e is `[{u'message': u'Could not authenticate you', u'code': 32}]`

What is problem?

Comment: Sounds like you should do some debugging on what e.message actually looks like

Comment: Presumably you expected `e` to be a `TweepError` exception here? Yet from your error message I'd say it is a *different* error instead. Without your code we'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly access it wrong, because message and code are alongside each other, code does not belong to the message. But also your error message is inconsistent with what you think `e` is. So try these options: `e.code`, `e["code"]`, `e[0].code`, `e[0]["code"]`